# Is a word embedding a vector or a function?

Tags: terminology, natural-language

Is a word embedding a vector or a function? I have read contradicting statements:

[Function](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-NLP-RNNs-Representations/):

> A word embedding $W: \text{words} \rightarrow R^n$ is is a paramaterized function mapping words in some language to high-dimensional vectors.

[Vector](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P14-2050.pdf):

> Most recently, it has been proposed to represent words as dense vector [...]. These representations, referred to as “neural embeddings” or “word embeddings”, have been shown to perform well across a variety of tasks

Comment: Isn't the second quote saying that each word is mapped to a vector, i.e. describes exactly the same $\mathrm{words}\to\mathbb R^n$ mapping as the first quote?

Comment: This seems perfectly on topic to me.

Comment: It is standard in practice to use the same name for function, and its value when the input parameter is known.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to think of word embedding as a function that turns a word into a vector.

For instance, in word2vec, we can have words like "man", "king" and "queen" be vectors through word embedding.

The result is that we can do operations like "king" - "queen" + "man" = "woman".